# HTML ul/li Tree to PHP Array using phpQuery

Tags: php, mysql, phpquery

I want to use [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) for parsing DOM Elements. Here is [the HTML tree](http://dropship.mondialdeal.com/tmp/ul-tree.html) that i want to import into MySQL db using a PHP recursive function.

The MySQL db that will store the tree as categories (with sub, sub, .., categories)

```
create table categories
(
    categorie_id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
    categorie_id_parent int(11) not null,
    categorie_nom varchar(255) not null
)
```

Here is my pseudocode :

```
function getCategories( $pq_object, $last_generated_mysql_id )
{
    // for every element of $pq_object on same lvl
    {
        // insert into mysql $pq_object->a->name
        // and with categorie_id_parent as $last_generated_mysql_id if has parent

        // going deeper for every child
        getCategories( $pq_object->children(), mysql_insert_id() );
    } 
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually did it :

```
function getCats( $categorie_id_parent, $cats )
{
    echo "<ul>";

    foreach ( $cats as $ch )
    {
        $categorie_nom = mysql_real_escape_string( pq($ch)->find("a:first")->text() );

        // Inserting categories
        $query_categorie = "SELECT categorie_id FROM categories WHERE categorie_id_parent='".$categorie_id_parent."' AND categorie_nom LIKE '".$categorie_nom."' LIMIT 1";
        $result_categorie = mysql_query( $query_categorie ) or die ( mysql_error() );

        $categorie_id = 0;

        if ( mysql_num_rows( $result_categorie ) )
        {
            $row_categorie = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result_categorie );

            $categorie_id = $row_categorie['categorie_id'];
        }
        else
        {
            $query_insert = "INSERT INTO categories (categorie_id_parent, categorie_nom) VALUES ('".$categorie_id_parent."', '".$categorie_nom."')";
            mysql_query( $query_insert ) or die ( mysql_error() );

            $categorie_id = mysql_insert_id();
        }

        // if we have any subcategories
        if ( pq($ch)->children()->children()->length )
        {
            echo "<li>".pq($ch)->find("a:first")->text()."</li>";

            // going deeper
            getCats( $categorie_id, pq($ch)->children()->children() );
        }
        // If no subcategories, show the last link name and href
        else
            echo "<li>".pq($ch)->find('a:first')->text()." ".pq($ch)->find('a:first')->attr('href')."</li>";
    }

    echo "</ul>";
}
```